# CSS Accordion - Something in this CSS has caused me to lose a margin/border at the top of the page

Tags: css, border, accordion, margin

Everything is working on the page as I want it to and the missing margin/border isn't actually too much of an issue, but if there's an easy fix or it's easy to identify -why- it's doing this that would be great.

Here's an image of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Xmb.jpg

As you can see, the left image has no border, so it's obscuring the logout button for the site.

Here's the CSS that I'm using:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Any help welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I see this on a live link ?

Comment: CSS alone doesn't tell us which element is causing the problem here. What styles in all that CSS apply to the image in question?

Comment: That's the problem, the CSS is used for an accordion, but something in there is affecting the top of the page as seen in the image.

Comment: Well I've narrowed it down to something in the reset.

Comment: Narrowed it down even further, I'm 99% sure it's the last line of CSS that I've kept up above...

Answer (score 0):

Changing this CSS reset:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

to this CSS reset:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/
div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Fixed the problem that I was having. - All I did was remove "body" from that reset.